# Find a String but return the previous String

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a String in a Textfile. I'm using the RegEx Method for that. But I need to get the Previous String, which is existing before the found String, as Method  Output. How can i do it with c#? Can anyone give me some Idea?

For Example:
In that Textfile is a Line with `'routerbl router0000;'`
I'm searching `'router0000;'` and if i find `'router0000;'` then i want to get `'routerbl'`.

Comment: We need more examples of possible strings, what should and shouldn't match and what needs to be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilities

1. Match what you want using a [capturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#matched_subexpression), something like this

   ```
   (\S+)\s+router0000
   ```

   and you will find your result in the capturing group 1
2. Match your pattern and ensure the following string with a [lookahead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion)

   ```
   \S+(?=\s+router0000)
   ```

   this will match only the part you want.

Comment: thx for Help. I was trying second possibility and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

It won't answer your question about regular expressions, but if the only rule is to return the first part of your string before a specific sub-string, then you could using something more simple than regexp:

```
string test = "routerbl router0000;";
string matchingValue = "router000";

int matchingValueIndex = test.IndexOf(matchingValue);
string leftPart;
if (matchingValueIndex >= 0)
{
    leftPart = test.Substring(0, matchingValueIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways

- Use groups `(routerbl) (router0000)`, and use the first group
- Positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `routerbl (?=router000)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the expression `(.*)(?=\srouter0000)` to find the text before the router0000 text.

```
string resultString = null;
try
{
    resultString = Regex.Match(part, @"(.*)(?=\srouter0000)", RegexOptions.Multiline).Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Hmm actually the solution by @stema is nicer as it uses `\S` instead of `.*`, however the idea is the same.

Comment: I think `.*` is a better answer because it assumes less about the requirements the questioner didn't specify.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that is an example of a complete line:

```
Regex expression = new Regex("(.*) router0000");
```

Comment: This matches the `router0000` part, not the `routerbl` part.

Comment: "i'm searching 'router0000;' and if i find 'router0000;' then i want to get 'routerbl.'" He wants to get the part at the beginning of the line. I'm matching based on what he said to match and returning what he wanted to return.

Comment: Actually I suppose in this instance the look behind is not really needed.

Comment: I agree. In that case it should be `(.*)(?=\srouter0000)` as this one will not match the suffix. In your case you had to take the second match group.